# Passing data between controllers in OnsenUI+AngularJS+PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I found similar questions to mine being asked, and answered, but I think my scenario is different. I started from the sample code here [enter link description here](https://onsen.io/blog/onsen-ui-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-angularjs-sample-application/) for a simple app with a sliding menu that uses Google Maps.

I am creating a prototype that lets users submit new items that are added to a list of pending items, and then added to the map. I am now concentrating on the first part - letting users create items, and updating the list of pending submissions automatically. I then added a simple form to create new item:

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar fixed-style ng-controller="SlidingMenuController">
        <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">New Submission</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-row style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
        <ons-col ng-controller="NewSubmissionController">
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Please insert a brief description of your find and its material.</p>
             <textarea style="width: 97%;" id="subDescrText" class="textarea" rows="4" placeholder="Type your description here..." value="" ng-model="subDescription"></textarea>
        <ons-button style="margin-top: 24px;" ng-click="doStore()">
            Store
        </ons-button>
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-page>
```

And another page to list the created submissions:

```
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left">
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
        <div class="center">Pending Submissions</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <ons-list id="pendingList" var="aPendingList" ng-controller="PendingListController">
            <ons-list-item ng-repeat="pi in pendingItems">
                <p>{{pi.description}}</p>
                <span>{{pi.material}}</span>
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
    </div>div>
    <p style="margin-top: 12px; text-align: center; width: 100%;" >
        <ons-button ng-click="">
            Upload All
        </ons-button>
    </p>
</ons-page>
```

I then added these controllers:

```
app.controller('NewSubmissionController', function($scope) {
    $scope.selMat;
    $scope.subDescription;

    $scope.doStore = function() {
        alert('In NewSubmissionController.doStore() - Sel material: ' + $scope.selMat + '\nDescr: ' + $scope.subDescription);

        var newPI = new SubmissionItem($scope.selMat, $scope.subDescription, '');
        $scope.$emit('newPI', newPI);
        slidingMenu.setMainPage('pendingList.html', {closeMenu: true});
    };

});

// Pending list controller
app.controller('PendingListController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pendingItems = [];
    $scope.$on('newSubEvent', function(e, subMat, descr) {
        alert('In PendingListController, event newSubEvent - sub mat: ' + subMat + '\nDescription: ' + descr);
    });

    $scope.addPendingItem = function(newPi) {
        alert('In PendingListController.addPendingItem() - ' + newPi);
        $scope.pendingItems.unshift(newPi);
        // Some code here to update the list of pending submissions...
    };
});
```

In this version I had tried to use the event system as suggested by other replies here. Unfortunately it doesn't work, because the two controller are not child and parent. Moving *PendingListController* inside *NewSubmissionController* doesn't work either, and I reckon it's because the two controllers are on two different views.

What is the best solution to call PendingListController.addPendingItem() from NewSubmissionController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using multiple pages which require [Multiple Pages Managing Pattern](https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#ManagingMultiplePages).

So from there, you have the choices to add a main controller for the main navigation page (in your case, that would be sliding menu page), so then you can share the $rootScope among the child controllers.

It's advisable to use Dependency Injection as your solution, you can use service or factory to help "passing/sharing" your data between controllers.

Demo code below shows:

- how you can utilise Service to let controllers *communicate*
- how is $rootScope can be used to live update data

Using service to share data between controllers

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('mainService', function($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.userList = [];

    self.login = function(newUser) {
      self.userList.push(newUser + ' ' + (self.userList.length + 1));
      return self.userList;
    };
  })

.controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, mainService) {

  $scope.mainAddUser = function() {
    $rootScope.users = mainService.login('Main');
  };
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, mainService) {
  $scope.loginAddUser = function() {
    $rootScope.users = mainService.login('Login');
  };
});
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/OvG0oj6EmDU5GMi1eBaU?p=preview

Comment: Just so that I get it - since in my case I have the sliding menu controller in the main navigation page, I should define my _NewSubmissionController_ and _PendingListController_ as its child controllers, so that they can use the scope of the sliding menu controller as root scope?

Comment: I restructured my code following your example, and it worked. I'm grateful, but I would like to understand better. Why does it work? The controllers are not defined as the children of anything else, so what is the rootScope? And by the way, is there any good tutorial/documentation that goes into these topics? I could follow and understand the basic one on Angular's web site, but it stops wayyy earlier than these topics.

Comment: It's determined by where you place your controllers in the html template. In short, the scope is inherited from parent to child view: (rootScope -> parent scope -> child scope), so child can still access its parents scope. For more detailed explanations, i found [Angular Scope Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#angular-scope-inheritance) has good example & diagrams you can follow. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send and capture events between controllers (which don't share `$scope`), use `$rootScope` and its methods `$on` and `$broadcast`:

```
myApp.controller("fooCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope){
        $scope.foo = "foo";

        $scope.broadcast = function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("fooChange", $scope.foo);
        };
});

myApp.controller("barCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope){
        $scope.bar = null;

        $rootScope.$on("fooChange", function(e, data){
            $scope.bar = data;
        });
});
```

After capturing the event in `barCtrl`, you can do the `PendingListController.addPendingItem()` call.

DEMO http://jsbin.com/kolorixoti/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The example in the demo works, but when I integrate it in my existing code, something odd happens. The first time I call _PendingListController.addPendingItem()_ I get no alert. The second time I get them once. The third time, two sets of alerts. And so on.